# Virtman - Error with VM - Host does not support domain type

Tags: arch-linux, kvm, virt-manager

I was using Ubuntu until I recently changed to Arch (Manjaro). However, when re-installing Virt-Manager again, I wanted to start the old virtual machines. The configuration hasn't changed but I encounter errors:

The machine can't get stated any more and I receive the following error message:

```
Error launching details: Host does not support domain type kvm 
with machine 'pc-i440fx-focal' for virtualization type 'hvm' with
architecture 'x86_64'

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/vmwindow.py", line 40, in get_instance
    cls._instances[key] = vmmVMWindow(vm)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/vmwindow.py", line 83, in __init__
    self._details = vmmDetails(self.vm, self.builder, self.topwin,
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/details/details.py", line 389, in __init__
    self._init_details()
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/details/details.py", line 807, in _init_details
    vmmAddHardware.build_video_combo(self.vm, video_dev)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/addhardware.py", line 816, in build_video_combo
    default = DeviceVideo.default_model(vm.xmlobj)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtinst/devices/video.py", line 47, in default_model
    if (guest.lookup_domcaps().supports_video_virtio() and
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtinst/guest.py", line 656, in lookup_domcaps
    if not self._domcaps or not _compare(self._domcaps):
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtinst/guest.py", line 646, in _compare
    if self.os.machine and not _compare_machine(domcaps):
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtinst/guest.py", line 633, in _compare_machine
    capsinfo = self.lookup_capsinfo()
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtinst/guest.py", line 674, in lookup_capsinfo
    self._capsinfo = self.conn.caps.guest_lookup(
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtinst/capabilities.py", line 319, in guest_lookup
    raise ValueError(msg)
ValueError: Host does not support domain type kvm with machine 'pc-i440fx-focal' 
for virtualization type 'hvm' with architecture 'x86_64'
```

I did not make any changes to the BIOS settings or anything. So virtualization in general should still work fine.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I finally got it.

When I looked at the configuration it contained the line:

```
<type arch="x86_64" machine="pc-i440fx-focal">hvm</type>
```

where as a newly build machine contains the slightly different line:

```
<type arch="x86_64" machine="pc-i440fx-7.0">hvm</type>
```

So it looks like some packages for the machine are different between Ubuntu and Arch, I guess.